# Should WinOps be a tag?

Tags: discussion

Per Wikipedia:

> WinOps (a portmanteau of "Windows" and "DevOps") is a term used
>   referring to the cultural movement of DevOps practices for a
>   Microsoft-centric view. It emphasizes the use of the cloud,
>   automation and integrating development and IT operations into one
>   fluid method on the Windows platform.

Should this be a predefined tag to encourage and grant visibility of DevOps on Windows specific questions?

Comment: I'm unsure it is needed, I feel question when scoped enough will include a azure/windows tag, so I don't feel its necessary to have a "meta" tag for it.

Comment: That's true, "Windows" itself might be more obvious/explicit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As this is already a devops-related site, having a tag named [windows](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) should specifically mean the same thing as `Winops` (acc to the definition in your question).

Also, it would be more easy (and less confusing) [Just my opinion, though] for new users and existing users to look up and understand, than [winops](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winops).